# Computer Keeps Crashing After Replacing RAM

Tags: imac, memory

Recently I replaced my RAM in my Mid 2009 iMac. I replaced the current RAM with 2 x 4 Gb. sticks of RAM. However, now that I replaced the RAM, my computer has started to randomly crash often although I am able to use it for 10-60 minute periods before the crash. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is my crash log:

```
Anonymous UUID:       57FFE67A-A6EF-8CEB-EE47-B6F531884D5F
Thu Feb 19 18:06:37 2015
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80090dcc1d): Kernel trap at 0xffffef7f897fb2ca, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffef7f897fb2ca, CR3: 0x000000000bfe4000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0000000000000007, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0xffffff81075a1400
RSP: 0xffffff810cadb028, RBP: 0xffffff810cadb140, RSI: 0xffffff81075a1400, RDI: 0xffffff801d8fc558
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff810cadb0dc, R10: 0x00000000000001b0, R11: 0x0000000000000010
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff801d8fc558, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0xffffff801d8fc950
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffef7f897fb2ca, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffef7f897fb2ca, Error code: 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU: 0x0
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810cadacb0 : 0xffffff8009023139 
0xffffff810cadad30 : 0xffffff80090dcc1d 
0xffffff810cadaf00 : 0xffffff80090f4486 
0xffffff810cadaf20 : 0xffffef7f897fb2ca 
0xffffff810cadb140 : 0xffffff80092cdc81 
0xffffff810cadb450 : 0xffffff80092dd2fb 
0xffffff810cadb580 : 0xffffff80092dc9f7 
0xffffff810cadb760 : 0xffffff80092d61a3 
0xffffff810cadbb90 : 0xffffff80092c9f56 
0xffffff810cadbbe0 : 0xffffff80092ca252 
0xffffff810cadbdc0 : 0xffffff80092b83bd 
0xffffff810cadbde0 : 0xffffff8009253df3 
0xffffff810cadbe10 : 0xffffff80092351ce 
0xffffff810cadbeb0 : 0xffffff800922c89c 
0xffffff810cadbf60 : 0xffffff80092340b9 
0xffffff810cadbfb0 : 0xffffff80090d7c67 
> 
> 
BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Mac OS version:
13F34
Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Dec 17 19:05:52 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 45486BF2-BDDE-34CB-8C71-606FF3FE181B
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009000000
System model name: iMac9,1 (Mac-F2218EA9)
System uptime in nanoseconds: 458544345171
last loaded kext at 295548262378: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f8a59a000, size 65536)
last unloaded kext at 356989742446: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f8a59a000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.7f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.34
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.7
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.21
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.7f4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.2
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
System Profile:
Model: iMac9,1, BootROM IM91.008D.B08, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.44f0
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400, NVIDIA GeForce 9400, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x01BA, 0x202020202020202020202020202020202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x01BA, 0x202020202020202020202020202020202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD1600AAJS-40H3A0, 160.04 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GA11N
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: USB Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel panic logs are relating directly to your ram. The characters after your backtrace are memory addresses.

Your solution is to reseat your ram first, try one stick at a time when starting up, then lastly replace the ram stick if needed. 
Also, the issue could be the ram slot on the logic board in which case it may need to be replaced.